# Django - posts.Post.None

Tags: django

I am working on a django project and I have 2 models that look like this:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='playlist_user')
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
    genre       = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    track       = models.ManyToManyField('Post',related_name='playlist_track')

class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
    audiofile   = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_image_path,null=True)
    genre       = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
```

and this view:

```
def userprofileview(request):
    own_tracks = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    playlist_ = Playlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context = {
    'own_tracks':own_tracks,
    'playlist_':playlist_
}
return render(request,'userprofile.html',context)
```

but when I try to query the posts from the playlist like this:

```
{% for object in playlist_ %}
{{ object.track }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get:

```
posts.Post.None
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: It is `{{ object.track.all }}` (but you likely should *iterate* over the items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the related objects, you need to add `.all` at the end:

```
{% for object in playlist_ %}
    {% for post in object.track.all %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To avoid the *N+1 problem*, you can use [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
def userprofileview(request):
    own_tracks = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    playlist_ = Playlist.objects.filter(user=request.user).prefetch_related('post')
context = {
    'own_tracks':own_tracks,
    'playlist_':playlist_
}
return render(request,'userprofile.html',context)
```

Comment: I get the user but not the title of the track. I have `{% for object in playlist_.all %}{{ object.user }} - {{ object.title }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: @pyjama: but your `Playlist` object has no title, only the `track` has a title, hence `{{ object.title }}` will not work (since `object` is `Playlist` object).

Comment: Sorry I ment `{{ object.track.title }}`

Comment: @pyjama: but you used a many-to-many field, hence there is no single track, there are zero, one or more tracks, hence you will need to iterate over the `track` objects.

Comment: So I would need to use a ForeignKey instead of the M2M Field so that I can then do: `{% for object in playlist_.all %}{{ object.track.user }} - {{ object.track.title }}{% endfor %}` ? But will this get me all the tracks from the playlist?

Comment: @Pyjama: no, if is a `ForeignKey`, it will give you one `track` object. It looks however odd that a `Playlist` contains *one* `Track`. So it makes not much sense what you aim to render I guess. If you want to add the user over all tracks, you can use `{% for object in playlist_ %}{% for post in object.track.all %}{{ object.user }} - {{ track.title }} {% endfor %}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: Ive added this `liked_posts_playlist_   = Playlist.objects.filter(track=request.user.post_likes.all()[0])` to the `userprofileview` and shortened the template to `{% for object in liked_posts_playlist_ %}{{ object.structure|safe }}{% endfor %}`, but I get `list index out of range` when I log onto the page with another account.

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced `[0]` with  `.first()` and now it works